# VBA code will refresh pivots with SQL server source but not Excel source

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, refresh, pivot

I have written VBA code which takes a set of excel files and in turn opens them, refreshes the pivots, saves and closes the files. It works for any workbook that just has pivots which connect to SQL server to refresh the data. If the workbook also contains a pivot which is built off data held within the workbook itself then the process fails with the error:

**Cannot open pivot table source file: '"\nch\dfs\SharedArea\Private\BIS\Groups\KPI-Group\Pivots\ [Hand-Hygiene-Audits.xls"]QPS'**

As I've said the pivot table source is within the same sheet as the pivot. If I manually Refresh All in the workbook there are no issues. (QPS is the tab where the manual data and associated pivot are in this example)

(Please note that I had to add a space between the path and the filename as the Stackoverflow code formatting removes the backslash after \Pivots for some reason)

It is also worth noting that the square brackets are not shown normally around the filename, they only seem to appear within this error message. I have searched online and most people who have talked about the square bracket issue say its where files have been downloaded from IE. In my case all three affected files were produced from scratch in-house.

An extract of my code that deals with the refresh element is below. If you would like to see the rest of my code let me know and I will post it.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

```
Sub Refresh_BoardPivots_Standard()
'    On Error GoTo Errorhandler

Dim i
Dim errorText As String
Dim x
Dim objXL As Excel.Application
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

GetPivotsToRefresh ' populates array from SQL
For Each i In StandardBoardPiv
DoEvents
'If File_Exists(i) Then
    If isFileOpen(i) = True Then
    errorText = i
    Failed(failedIndex) = errorText
    failedIndex = failedIndex + 1
    Else
    objXL.Visible = True 'False
     objXL.Workbooks.Open FileName:=i
        If objXL.ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly = False Then
        BackgroundQuery = False
        objXL.ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
        objXL.Application.CalculateFull
        objXL.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        objXL.ActiveWorkbook.Save
        objXL.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        objXL.Quit
        Else
        errorText = i
        Failed(failedIndex) = errorText
        failedIndex = failedIndex + 1
        objXL.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        objXL.Quit
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    End If
'        Else
'        errorText = i
'        Failed(failedIndex) = errorText
'        failedIndex = failedIndex + 1
'    End If
DoEvents
If Ref = False Then
Exit For
End If

Next i

Exit Sub

'Errorhandler:
'
'errorText = i
'Failed(failedIndex) = errorText
'failedIndex = failedIndex + 1

'Resume Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like I can answer my own question, though I don't understand why my first approach worked for 85% of files.

My previous project which used this method used hard coded filenames which needed to be encased by double quotes when populating an array. My latest method stores the filenames in a sql table and loads them into the vba sub. Unfortunately I hadn't noticed that the double quotes were still there which were no longer required. The process still opened up and refreshed 85% of the files but threw that strange error on a few of them.

Quotes removed from the filenames and processes executes fine.